# Is material-ui friendly to form?

Tags: forms, material-ui

Recently, when I use React&material-ui to make a form, I find that many components do not have 'name' property, such as 'SelectField'. So I must get the value through a method. Is material-ui suitable for implementing a form? If the answer is yes, can you give me a intact example which uses some components such as 'TextField', 'SelectField', and how do I submit it?

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend connectin material-ui with redux-form:

http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/examples/material-ui/

Works fine as long as you pass component representing material-ui form into the Field from react redux

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

<Field
    name="username"
    id="username"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Username"
    label="Username"
    required
    iconName="person"
    component={TextField}
  />
```

And then you would have form values existing in redux state.

Comment: Oh, too much npm packages. If I don't want to install that, can I have other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This actually is not a material-ui specific issue i believe. You'll be in the same boat if you use simple `<input>` elements.

Basically what you want to do is get/set the value of a text box / checkbox when a user does some action or clicks submit. Material-ui just lets you do pretty, reusable and designed components so that you wont have to write them yourself.

To work easily with forms you would have do some additional coding from your side. I also suggest the great library `redux-form` but it would require you to also implement redux in your app (A great thing by itself but i dont know what are your requirements).

If you want another option then you can use https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react which is another great and popular library for managing forms and doesnt require redux

If you want to do things yourself then you can use recommendations from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html which in general tell you to have controlled components.

One final thing. Dont be afraid to use additional libraries and modules. The whole point in having hundreds thousands of modules is for people to use them =]